# Is it possible to create a non-forking vnc service?

Tags: linux, services, vnc, systemd, pid

I followed [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-22-04) to create a vnc service. The service is forking and uses a PID-file. My version of the service description — vncserver@.service — looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start TightVNC at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=interactive
Group=interactive
WorkingDirectory=/home/interactive

PIDFile=/home/interactive/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/touch /home/interactive/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1280x800 -localhost :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, the systemd-documentation includes the following under PIDFile:

> Note that PID files should be avoided in modern projects. Use
> Type=notify,Type=notify-reload or Type=simple where possible, which
> does not require use of PID files to determine the main process of a
> service and avoids needless forking.

Would it be possible to avoid forking and PID-files for the vnc-service?